# cucumber: command not found (in Mac OS)

Tags: macos, npm, cucumber, homebrew

I've tried installing Cucumber using:

**npm install -g cucumber**

and

**brew install cucumber-cpp**

In both cases it looks as it is installed successfully but when I try to run cucumber command I get:

**-bash: cucumber: command not found**

I say be missing something. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked using gem install cucumber.

It is also necessary to close the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: It probably has to do with your path, e.g. the first two may have installed in `/usr/local/bin` and that was not on your path, but gem installed in `/usr/bin` and that was in your path. The path is the first thing to check in situations like this where a command cannot be found. `echo $PATH`

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thanks!